# Is there a more efficient way to do this without all the "if" and "else" statements?

Tags: javascript, performance, if-statement

How would you program this more efficiently?

```
if( randomYear%4==0 ) { 
    if( randomYear%100==0 ) {
        if( randomYear%400==0 ) {
            randomDay = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random()*29);
        }
        else {
            randomDay = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random()*28);
        }
    else{
        randomDay = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random()*29);
    }
else{
    randomDay = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random()*28);
}
```

First off, i''m using math.floor because it includes 0 and excludes 1, which is what i'm looking for. The purpose of this is to determine if the variable 'randomYear' is a leap year and have the appropriate days in February.

I'm mainly concerned about all the if and else statements. BTW, i'm using Javascript.
Thank YOU SO much!!

Comment: Use the `Date` type, which does all of this for you.

Comment: You can also replace `1 + Math.floor()` with `Math.ceil()`

Comment: @jcsanyi - No you can't: `Math.random()` _might_ return `0`.

Answer (score 5):

You don't even need the math:

```
var tmp = new Date(year,1,29); // attempt to get February 29th
isleapyear = (tmp.getMonth() == 1);
```

Comment: This seems like the proverbial "right way to do it" to me. Creating a date 29 days after the beginning of February in the given year and then finding out whether the resulting date is still in the month of February is a beautiful solution that relies on the fact that JavaScript already "knows" a huge amount of details about leap years, time zones, etc., etc.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
var maxDays = 28;
if (randomYear%4 == 0 && (randomYear%100 != 0 || randomYear%400 == 0)) {
    maxDays = 29;
}
randomDay = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * maxDays);
```

Comment: +1. Or another option: `var maxDays = (randomYear%4 == 0 && (randomYear%100 != 0 || randomYear%400 == 0)) ? 29 : 28;`

Comment: If you're going to do that, why not go all out with: `randomDay = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * ((randomYear%4 == 0 && (randomYear%100 != 0 || randomYear%400 == 0)) ? 29 : 28));`

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with including a third party library, try this library:

http://momentjs.com/

And you can just do:

```
moment([2000]).isLeapYear()
```

to check if 2000 is a leap year and then you can do appropriate logic. Also you can check if 29th of Feb of a certain year exists or not using its validation api.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as given below.

```
function isLeapYear(year){
  return !(year%400) || ((year%100 > 0) && !(year%4)) ;
}

function getRandomDay(year){
  return 1 + Math.floor(Math.random()* (isLeapYear(year)?29:28))
}

var day = getRandomDay(2000);
```

Performance wise it might not make big changes. But this is the way to write organized re-usable code in less number of lines.